# Intercept another window's output

Tags: c++, x11, xorg

I have the project to develop an application that would allow a computer to 'send' a window to another computer.
In order to do that, I need, of course, to capture the concerned window's output from my program.
Google searches leaded me to no relevant result, neither with libX11 nor libxcb.

I also tried to record screenshots with `xwd` and `import`, but as they are quite slow, I'm getting up to 3.5 fps

Any help on how I could do that will be welcome (either using libX11, libxcb, or something else)

By the way, I attempt to use c++ for this program

Thanks for reading,

Edit:
The fps test was made without sending files. It was just like "I took screenshots for 5 minutes, and I got 900 pictures"

Comment: Why not use X11 forwarding? X was built to be network transparent, why clone the functionality it supports out of the box?

Comment: why not use VNC? "x11vnc -id your-window-id"

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to record screenshots and compress them before sending over network to make things faster. Also, you would need to decrease the quality  of the screenshots (user configurable) to make it faster.

Plus there are different techniques to send only the changes (diff of screenshots) to the other computer.

Comment: Actually, 3.5 fps is the speed of 'screenshot taking', without sending them over the network